# How to logically group elements using JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb

I have Booking.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name="booking")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Booking{
    @XmlElement(name="name", required = true, nillable = true)
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name="contact",required = true, nillable = true)
    private int contact;

    @XmlElement(name="startDate", required = true, nillable = true)
    private Date startDate;

    @XmlElement(name="endDate", required = true, nillable = true)
    private Date endDate;

    @XmlElement(name="address", required = true, nillable = true)
    private String address;
}
```

Which I am marsheling using JAXB, output displayed is as below

```
<booking>
    <name>RAHUL</name>
    <contact>9898989898</contact>
    <startDate>2013-08-12T00:00:00+05:30</startDate>
    <endDate>2013-01-12T00:00:00+05:30</endDate>
    <address>Mumbai</address>
</booking>
```

But I want output to be like below

```
<booking>
    <PersonalDetails>
          <name>RAHUL</name>
          <contact>9898989898</contact>
    </PersonalDetails>

    <startDate>2013-08-12T00:00:00+05:30</startDate>
    <endDate>2013-01-12T00:00:00+05:30</endDate>
    <address>Mumbai</address>
</booking>
```

I have checked XMLElementWrapper, but it works with Collection.
Note: I can not change my pojo Booking.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MOXy as your JAXB provider (I'm the MOXy) lead you could use the `@XmlPath` extension for this use case:

```
@XmlPath("PersonalDetails/name/text()")
```

Answer (score 0):

create class PersonalDetails (with name and contact) and use it as an attribute.